# Input string error after a spark-submit

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, input, submit

I'm trying to run some Spark Scala code :

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object EzRecoMRjobs {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setMaster("local")
    conf.setAppName("Product Cardinalities")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val dataset = sc.textFile(args(0))
    // Load parameters
    val customerIndex = args(1).toInt - 1
    val ProductIndex = args(2).toInt - 1
    val outputPath = args(3).toString


    val resu = dataset.map( line => { val orderId = line.split("\t")(0)
                                      val cols = line.split("\t")(1).split(";")
                                      cols(ProductIndex)
                                     })
        .map( x => (x,1) )
        .reduceByKey(_ + _)
        .saveAsTextFile(outputPath)

    sc.stop()

  }
}
```

This code works in Intellij and write the result in the "outputPath" folder. 
From my Intellij project I have generate a .jar file and I want to run this code with a spark-submit. So in my terminal I launch :

```
spark-submit \
  --jars /Users/users/Documents/TestScala/ezRecoPreBuild/target/ezRecoPreBuild-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  --class com.np6.scala.EzRecoMRjobs \
  --master local \
  /Users/users/Documents/DATA/data.txt 1 2 /Users/users/Documents/DATA/dossier
```

But I got this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/Users/users/Documents/DATA/dossier"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
    at com.np6.scala.EzRecoMRjobs$.main(ezRecoMRjobs.scala:51)
    at com.np6.scala.EzRecoMRjobs.main(ezRecoMRjobs.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

What's the reason of this error ? Thank's

Comment: may be you are running the old jar file. try clean and package again

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

The first application argument is expected to be the jar file path, so obviously your are getting a NumberFormatException, because your code is parsing the last  argument (which is a String) as a number.

The --jars flag is used to specify additional jars that will be used in your application.

You must run the spark-submit command in this way:

```
spark-submit \
  --class com.np6.scala.EzRecoMRjobs \
  --master local[*] \
/Users/users/Documents/TestScala/ezRecoPreBuild/target/ezRecoPreBuild-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /Users/users/Documents/DATA/data.txt 1 2 /Users/users/Documents/DATA/dossier
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's it ! Thank you